# google-cloud-datastore java client: Is there a way to infer schema and/or retrieve results as Json?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on datastore datasource for apache-spark based on spark datasource V2 api. I was able to implement using hard-coded single entity but couldn't generalize it. Either I need to infer entity schema and translate entity record into Spark Row or read entity record as json and let the user translate into scala product (datastore java client is REST based so the payload is being pulled as json). I could see "entity.properties" as json key-values from within IntelliJ debugger which includes everything I need (column name, value, type etc.) but I can't use entity.properties due to access restrictions. Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by switching to low level API https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore

full source for spark-datastore-connector https://github.com/sgireddy/spark-datastore-connector